# How to use Timer correctly in Java?

Tags: java, timer, task, timing

I am new at Java and trying to make a sample application for an Airplane where you can see the Flight, Airstrip, Status and ETA. The code I am using is:

```
private Object[] getEta() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int seconds = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    return new Object[] { 5 + new Random().nextInt(5) * 1000};
}

private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
        for (int i = model.getRowCount() -1; i >= 0; i--) {
            Object[] row = getEta();
            model.setValueAt(row[0], i, 3);
        }try{
            Thread.sleep(5000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is how can i count ETA of each flight with a delay of 5 seconds between each flight and that while there are 10 flights?

[image]

Comment: I didn’t understand the problem. Could you explain more clearly what is the desired program behaviour, and and what way does the current behaviour differ?

Comment: @OleV.V. i have to make an ETA for each flight so for example the first flight is going to land in 52 seconds, the second flight in 57 seconds, the third flight in 62 seconds. The flights have to land with a delay of 5 seconds

Comment: As an aside, as the code stands you don’t need the cast, assuming `table` is a `JTable`. `getModel()` returns a `TableModel`, and a `TableModel` has methods `getRowCount()` and `setValueAt()`.

Comment: I’m not sure I get it. Make `cal` a static field and for each call to `getEta()`, call `cal.add(Calendar.SECONDS, 5)` and return `cal.getTime()`?

Comment: I get the time for each flight, but the problem is i have to set the time with 5 seconds of delay for each flight. For example i have to see: 67(count till 0) 62(count till 0) 57 52

Comment: @Emre:  Just count seconds.  When you've counted 5, start the first flight, and so on